# How is req.isAuthenticated() in Passport JS implemented?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

In passportJS Documentation, I think passport `isAuthenticated` function not documented well.

How is `req.isAuthenticated()` in PassportJS implemented?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

For any request you can check if a user is authenticated or not using this method.

```
app.get('/some_path',checkAuthentication,function(req,res){
    //do something only if user is authenticated
});
function checkAuthentication(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        //req.isAuthenticated() will return true if user is logged in
        next();
    } else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me whats is exactly req.isAuthenticated do?
cause instead using req.isAuthenticated(), I can check whether the client is login or not using : `req.session.passport.user !== undefined` right?

Comment: Yes you can use that. isAuthenticated() is their own custom implementation of the same. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74)

Comment: @Kim comment solved for me. thanks!