# Passport/ExpressJS - How to Properly Maintain Session State with Cookies?

Tags: node.js, session, express, authentication, passport.js

> I am new to using Passport authentication with express between my
>   server and client (on two different ports), and am having great
>   trouble understanding both the concept of maintaining session state
>   with Passport and also trying to retrieve `req.session.passport.user`
>   in order to determine if a request is sent from a user that has
>   successfully logged on.
>
> ### Checking Persistent Session State with Passport
>
> In my code, I have a route to my profile page that uses my own
>   authenticated function. My login route uses
>   `passport.authenticate('local')`, however. **Should I be applying this
>   to ALL subsequent routes (like for my profile), or is my separate
>   authentication expected?**
>
> ### `req.session.passport` undefined
>
> **For some reason, the cookie that is sent with the /profile GET request is missing the `passport` object after a successful login (by
>   `passport.use('local-login')`)** It looks like the following if I
>   `console.log(req.session)` in `authenticated`. **Why is this?**
>
> ```
> Session {
>    cookie:
>     { path: '/',
>       _expires: 2017-07-11T01:38:30.087Z,
>       originalMaxAge: 14400000,
>       httpOnly: true,
>       secure: false } }
> ```
>
> ### Server Code
>
> ```
> // server.js
> let app = express();
> app.use(cors());
> import passportConfig from '../config/passport';
> passportConfig(passport); //apply passport configuration
> var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
> app.use(jsonParser);
> app.use(cookieParser('mySecret'));
> app.use(session({
>   secret: 'mySecret',
>   resave: false,
>   saveUninitialized: true,
>   cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 4*60*60*1000 }
> }));
> app.use(passport.initialize());
> app.use(passport.session());
>
> function authenticated (req, res, next) {
>     // req.session.passport is undefined
>     if (req.session.passport.user) {
>         next();
>     }
>     else {
>         res.redirect('/signup');
>     }
> }
>
> app.get('/profile', authenticated, (req, res) => {
>     // server code handling route
> }
>
> app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
>     session: true
> }), (req, res) => {
>      res.json({
>          email: req.user.local.email
>      });
> });
>
>
> // passport.js
> import User from '../models/User';
>
> export default function passportConfig(passport) {
>     passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
>         console.log('serializing user');
>         done(null, user.id);
>     });
>
>     // used to deserialize the user
>     passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
>         console.log('deserializing user');
>         User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
>             done(err, user);
>         });
>     });
>
>     passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
>         usernameField : 'email',
>         passwordField : 'password',
>         passReqToCallback : true
>     }, (req, email, password, done) => {
>         // if verification is successful
>         var newUser = new User();
>         // set credentials of newUser...
>         return done(null, newUser);
>     }));
> }
> ```
>
> ### Client Code
>
> ```
> // profile.js (client action code with react-redux)
> export function profile(terms, location) {
>   return (dispatch) => {
>       return fetch('profile',
>       {credentials: 'include'})
>       .then(response => response.json())
>       .then(json => { dispatch(profileSuccess(json)); })
>       .catch(error => dispatch(profileError(error)));
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> I am aware there are actually quite a lot of articles/posts available
>   of similar issues, but applying many of the different solutions have
>   all failed for me. Any help to my problem specifically is greatly
>   appreciated.

Comment: you can simply check if a user has successfully logged in by using req.isAuthenticated() method. Have you tried it?

Comment: I just tried this and it does not return true. according to this, that function also checks req.session.passport.user, so I would still have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820251/what-is-req-isauthenticated-passportjs