# How isAuthenticated() really works?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I start to learn node/express js, And i made a login system using `passport` , however i wanted to make a `member page` in my system only accessible for the users that already logged in , After some research i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820251/what-is-req-isauthenticated-passportjs) ,and it's pretty easy using `isAuthenticated()` "which is doesn't mentioned well in docs" ,

**But** Actually i don't understand how it works , how the program knows that the user is logged in or not ! , i'm so thankful if anyone can clear this thing for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't show any code so we don't really know what your site is doing, but presumably the initial authentication step sets an encrypted session cookie for that browser so whenever that browser makes a request in the near future, the server can test to see if an appropriate session cookie is present on that request.  If so, that browser is logged in.  This is generally how "logging in" works in a browser.

So, `isAuthenticated()` checks to see if the desired cookie is present on the request.  Depending upon the details of the code, some middleware may have already checked the cookie beforehand and set a property on the request that indicates if it is authenticated or not and `isAuthenticated()` is just checking that previously computed property.

And, as one can see in [the source code in the Github repository](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/597e289d6fa27a2c35d16dd411de284123e3817e/lib/http/request.js#L83), it is just checking to see if a `user` property already exists on the request which means some prior middleware has already examined the cookie associated with this request and determined it represents a valid user.

```
req.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
  }

  return (this[property]) ? true : false;
};
```

For more explanation see the comments in the passport code [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/597e289d6fa27a2c35d16dd411de284123e3817e/lib/authenticator.js#L197) as it describes generally how things work.

Comment: really THANKS sir ! the first part of answer really give me a better understanding for how logging in works and it clears my confusion about `sAuthenticated()` , i tested that in my chrome browser by watching `Cookies` section in Chrome kit  while i'm logging in and when i logged in it creates that `encrypted session cookie` that you mentioned , even when i cleared the cookies in the browser , the browser consider that the user have been logged out , and didn't give me an access for the member page (which is only accessible for logged in users)