# Node.js app login redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, authorization

I have created nodejs app where i have login form and then user is accessing main page of the app. But user can access main page without logging in. What can i do to prevent user from skipping logging in page?

Comment: any code sample you tried?

Comment: Check for session. And redirect user to login page if session is not started yet.

Comment: Which Authentication mechanism are you using? Passport has isAuthenticated method for request object. Please specify authentication mechanism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820251/what-is-req-isauthenticated-passportjs

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT token and middleware to prevent user from accessing the pages

Comment: In addition to your answer I would suggest to use [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) for all these authentication stuff.

Comment: @TGW thats a great suggestion