# Protecting route in node js with passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I've an express app for which the main server code is in **server.js** file.In **server.js** file there is a route `app.get('/dashboard',require('./dashboard/dashboard.js')`.

In **dashboard.js** file I've many routes like `/profile`,`/editProfile` etc.Now to protect all my `/dashboard` routes should I implement `req.isAuthenticated()` to each route? or is there any other way to protect all my `/dashboard` routes by implementing single authenticate function?

Answer (score 0):

create a middleware and add it to your /dashboard like this:
app.get('/dashboard', checkAuthentication , require('./dashboard/dashboard.js')

As explained here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38820680/2988950

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a middleware function before reaching the dashboard routes.

```
app.get('/dashboard',
(req, res, next) => {
  // Run passport isAuthenticated() here.
  // If true, next();
  // If false, throw
},
require('./dashboard/dashboard.js');
```

Comment: we have to replace app.get() with app.use() here.Its working now.Thank you.