# Passport with express and nextjs

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, passport.js

I'm implementing a login using NextJS, Express and Passport. I've setup Passport and when I try to use the function req.isAuthenticated() its says it's not defined.

```
  server.get("/profilePage", (res, req) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
       if (req.user.accountType === "user") {
```

If I use this this solution ([How is req.isAuthenticated() in Passport JS implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820251/how-is-req-isauthenticated-in-passport-js-implemented)) I'm not able to get data from the req

How I'm able to solve this?

EDIT:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { log } = require("console");
//new branch
//Express & Passport
const express = require("express"),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  session = require("express-session"),
  passport = require("passport"),
  bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  { createServer } = require("https");

require("./server/config/passport.js")(passport);

//Next
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

//AWS
const aws = require("aws-sdk"),
  dd = new aws.DynamoDB(),
  tableName = "UsersDB";

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    })
  );

  server.use(passport.initialize());
  server.use(passport.session());

  //HomePage
  server.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, "/index", req.query);
  });

  //Login
  server.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, "/testLogin", req.query);
  });

  server.post(
    "/login",
    passport.authenticate("local-login", {
      successRedirect: "/profilePage",
      failureRedirect: "/login",
    })
  );

server.get("/profilePage", (res, req) => {
    console.log(req.user.username)
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
       if (req.user.accountType === "user") {
        res.redirect("/test"); 
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/testProfileReciveData");
    }
  }
  });
```

config/passport if from here: https://github.com/christianboutin/passportjs-dynamodb/blob/master/config/passport.js

EDIT2: I think the main issue is that I cannot read req.user. When I try to console log req I get and object, but when I try to read req.user is says undefined. I check req and there is a field named user.

Comment: Please add the code how you initialize Passport. Also you need to call passport.authenticate show where and how you do that.

Comment: Just updated the code